# How to get records(Standard/Custom) on two tables in same visualforce page

Tags: visualforce

I need to get Account records on two table format in same visualforce
Eg: first table is disply 10 account records list and second table is display after 10 to 20 records list in same visualforce page (display the second table record list also first table below)

Comment: can you share your code what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [OFFSET](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm) to display query result.

If you have only two table then you can create two queries to display records.

```
List<Account> accountList1 = [Select Id, Name from Account limit 10 ORDER By CreatedDate]; // This will display first 10 records

List<Account> accountList2 = [Select Id, Name from Account limit 10 OFFSET 10 ORDER By CreatedDate]; // This will display records from 10 to 20
```

Then you can bind these list to VF page to dislpay 2 tables.